# How to Remove in Bulk Specific Website from Chrome's History?

Tags: browser, delete, history

I want to remove specific website mentions from Chrome's history on Android but doing it one by one will take a lot of time.

For example on Chrome for desktop, you can remove specific website mentions from history using bulk action.

I haven't found a way to do that on Chrome for Android. I though maybe I can access history of my smartphone on desktop and do removals but I can't find a way.

Comment: [No not possible](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/18099621/how-to-delete-web-history-for-a-specific-website?hl=en&msgid=18115145) ; IDK of any app that does this

Comment: Can I delete entire history and then restore entire history from Chrome cloud backup or something?

Comment: I don't think so